# socket error when starting turtlebot 2

Tags: ros, turtlebot2, turtlebot, groovy-turtlebot, kobuki

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is some error messages like this when starting.
**$roslaunch turtlebot_bringup minimal.launch**

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <bound method XmlRpcNode.run of <rosgraph.xmlrpc.XmlRpcNode object at 0xb2748ac>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosgraph/xmlrpc.py", line 221, in run
    self._run()
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosgraph/xmlrpc.py", line 291, in _run
    self._run_init()
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosgraph/xmlrpc.py", line 240, in _run_init
    self.server = ThreadingXMLRPCServer((bind_address, port), log_requests)
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosgraph/xmlrpc.py", line 121, in __init__
    SimpleXMLRPCServer.__init__(self, addr, SilenceableXMLRPCRequestHandler, log_requests)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SimpleXMLRPCServer.py", line 593, in __init__
    SocketServer.TCPServer.__init__(self, addr, requestHandler, bind_and_activate)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 408, in __init__
    self.server_bind()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 419, in server_bind
    self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 98] Address already in use
nodelet: /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/DenseStorage.h:69: Eigen::internal::plain_array<T, Size, MatrixOrArrayOptions, 16>::plain_array() [with T = float, int Size = 4, int MatrixOrArrayOptions = 0]: Assertion `(reinterpret_cast<size_t>(array) & 0xf) == 0 && "this assertion is explained here: " "eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/TopicUnalignedArrayAssert.html" " **** READ THIS WEB PAGE !!! ****"' failed.
[FATAL] [1364184119.740399921]: Service call failed!
[FATAL] [1364184119.740399911]: Service call failed!
[mobile_base_nodelet_manager-4] process has died [pid 10142, exit code -6, cmd /opt/ros/groovy/lib/nodelet/nodelet manager __name:=mobile_base_nodelet_manager __log:=/home/turtlebot/.ros/log/b9f2cc7e-94f3-11e2-8ee7-446d57b4d698/mobile_base_nodelet_manager-4.log].
log file: /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/b9f2cc7e-94f3-11e2-8ee7-446d57b4d698/mobile_base_nodelet_manager-4*.log
[bumper2pointcloud-8] process has died [pid 10412, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/groovy/lib/nodelet/nodelet load kobuki_bumper2pc/Bumper2PcNodelet mobile_base_nodelet_manager bumper2pointcloud/pointcloud:=mobile_base/sensors/bumper_pointcloud bumper2pointcloud/cliff_events:=mobile_base/events/cliff bumper2pointcloud/bumper_events:=mobile_base/events/bumper __name:=bumper2pointcloud __log:=/home/turtlebot/.ros/log/b9f2cc7e-94f3-11e2-8ee7-446d57b4d698/bumper2pointcloud-8.log].
log file: /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/b9f2cc7e-94f3-11e2-8ee7-446d57b4d698/bumper2pointcloud-8*.log
[mobile_base-5] process has died [pid 10158, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/groovy/lib/nodelet/nodelet load kobuki_node/KobukiNodelet mobile_base_nodelet_manager mobile_base/odom:=odom mobile_base/enable:=enable mobile_base/disable:=disable mobile_base/joint_states:=joint_states __name:=mobile_base __log:=/home/turtlebot/.ros/log/b9f2cc7e-94f3-11e2-8ee7-446d57b4d698/mobile_base-5.log].
log file: /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/b9f2cc7e-94f3-11e2-8ee7-446d57b4d698/mobile_base-5*.log
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59063/socket-error-when-starting-turtlebot-2/) by [hiranya](https://answers.ros.org/users/3446/hiranya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 104 on 2013-03-24

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on 2013-03-26**:
Looks like two different problems. Let's start with socket error. This can happen if driver is already running. What happen if you roslaunch minimal.launch just after startup? Can you also verify that ros is nor running before?  (execute sudo killall ros)

**Comment by [hiranya](https://answers.ros.org/users/3446/hiranya/) on 2013-03-27**:
@jorge : thanks.why dont we have command like "sudo service turtlebot stop" in groovy instead of kill all?

**Comment by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on 2013-03-27**:
normally you don't need it. Ctrl+C should do the job, unless you launched ros automatically at startup

**Comment by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on 2013-03-29**:
All the errors disappeared? I would have said that there're something more wrong...

**Comment by [CarolineQ](https://answers.ros.org/users/4109/carolineq/) on 2013-04-02**:
I have the same problem than your second one (Sevice call failed for the nodelet) when I launch minimal.launch. But it doesn't appear each time. Sometimes it starts well but most of the time I got the error... Did you solve it ? Thanks

**Comment by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on 2013-04-02**:
Maybe is related with the laptop you use; what's the model?

**Comment by [CarolineQ](https://answers.ros.org/users/4109/carolineq/) on 2013-04-02**:
@jorge, the laptop I am using is an Asus Eee PC, why do you think it can be related to this ?

**Comment by [hiranya](https://answers.ros.org/users/3446/hiranya/) on 2013-04-03**:
@jorge I manage to run applications except android panorama app(desktop one is working).Do you have any idea?  @CarolineQ please upgrade the broken Linux packages of your laptop(turtlebot) then build turtlebot applications by source. then you can run the applications.

**Comment by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on 2013-04-08**:
@hiranya what's wrong with panorama? Can you run it without the Android front-end (roslaunch turtlebot_panorama panorama.launch)? Maybe can be the issue of another ROS answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Answer second problem: If you installed by USB(pre-oders turtlebot usb have this broken packages) you can upgrade the broken packages. you can check that from synaptic manager and select all the broken packages and upgrade it. Then you can download turtlebot-apps(kobuki_desktop turtlebot turtlebot_apps turtlebot_viz) source then build.
make sure you have created udev rule

kobuki's udev rules

```
. /opt/ros/groovy/setup.bash
rosrun kobuki_ftdi create_udev_rules
```

you can run the applications except android panorama.

---

Originally posted by [hiranya](https://answers.ros.org/users/3446/hiranya/) with karma: 104 on 2013-04-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [CarolineQ](https://answers.ros.org/users/4109/carolineq/) on 2013-04-03**:
I don't have any broken package in the synaptic manager...

**Comment by [hiranya](https://answers.ros.org/users/3446/hiranya/) on 2013-04-03**:
Did you try to build from source and run apps?

**Comment by [mkeenan](https://answers.ros.org/users/14056/mkeenan/) on 2014-03-30**:
I'm having the same issue. Was there ever a solution? The Kobuki just stopped communicating all of the sudden.